# How to retry Ansible task that may fail?

Tags: ansible

In my Ansible play I am restarting database then trying to do some operations on it. Restart command returns as soon as restart is started, not when db is up. Next command tries to connect to the database. That command my fail when db is not up.

I want to retry my second command a few times. If last retry fails, I want to fail my play.

When I do retries as follows

```yaml
retries: 3
delay: 5
```

Then retries are not executed at all, because first command execution fails whole play. I could add  `ignore_errors: yes` but that way play will pass even if all retries failed. Is there a easy way to retry failures until I have success, but fail when no success from last retry?

Comment: Please post the whole task. I don't understand your concern -- first execution should not fail the play if you write it correctly.

Comment: The concern seems clear to me. I see the same behavior. When the first attempt fails, Ansible fails the whole playbook. It shouldn't be like that, but it is. Perhaps the `until` command is necessary?

Comment: Worth noting to others who find this is that `retries` is part of a `loop` and needs an `until` to work. Without `until` it will silently fail.
https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/20802

Answer (score 133, accepted):

I don't understand your claim that the "*first command execution fails whole play*". It wouldn't make sense if Ansible behaved this way.

The following task:

```
- command: /usr/bin/false
  retries: 3
  delay: 3
  register: result
  until: result.rc == 0
```

produces:

```
TASK [command] ******************************************************************************************
FAILED - RETRYING: command (3 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: command (2 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: command (1 retries left).
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"attempts": 3, "changed": true, "cmd": ["/usr/bin/false"], "delta": "0:00:00.003883", "end": "2017-05-23 21:39:51.669623", "failed": true, "rc": 1, "start": "2017-05-23 21:39:51.665740", "stderr": "", "stderr_lines": [], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
```

which seems to be exactly what you want.

Comment: thats right. my task had wrong condition in 'until' section.

Comment: as pointed in the answer below, small improvement would be `until: result is not failed`

Comment: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check 'result.rc == 0' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (result.rc == 0): 'dict object' has no attribute 'rc'"

Comment: It seems to me that 'result.rc == 0' way doesn't work any more, at least for me it is not working and I am using Ansible 2.11.2

Answer (score 38):

Not sure if this is Ansible tower specific, but I am using:

```
- command: /usr/bin/false
  register: result
  retries: 3
  delay: 10
  until: result is not failed
```

Answer (score 20):

Consider using [`wait_for`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/wait_for_module.html) module. It waits for a condition before continuing, for example for a port to become open or closed, for a file to exist or not, or for some content in a file.

Without seeing the rest of your playbook, consider the following example:

```
- name: Wait for db server to restart
  local_action:
    wait_for:
      host=192.168.50.4
      port=3306
      delay=1
      timeout=300
```

You can also adapt it as a handler and obviously change this snippet to suit your use-case.

Answer (score 1):

For the following task:

```
- hosts: all
become: yes
tasks:
- name: create the 'myusername' user
  user: name=myusername append=yes state=present createhome=yes shell=/bin/bash
```

I was not sure weather the remote was ready yet (because this was a newly spinned node). So I had to try those retries and delays stuff. Unfortunately with no luck. For now I ended up creating a wrapper in my bash script to achieve the needed behavior.

```
#!/bin/bash

STATUS_CODE=1
TRY=1
while [ "$STATUS_CODE" -ge 1 ]
do
  if [ $TRY -gt 5 ];
  then
    echo Retried to connect to node 5 times and failed. Exiting
    exit 1
  fi

  ansible-playbook -i $HOSTS_FILE user.yml
  STATUS_CODE=$?
  TRY=$(( $TRY + 1 ))

  if [ $STATUS_CODE -ge 1 ]
  then
    echo Retry to connect to node in 5 seconds
    sleep 5
  fi
done
```

Still in hopes to make it a cleaner way using ansible-playbook yml. Anyone got suggestions on this?

Comment: You can wait for a connection to the new node. See the answer of Mxx above