# Install multiple local rpms using Ansible

Tags: ansible, yum

I have to install dozen of rpms located in a specific directory using ansible. Right now I'm using the syntax like:

```
- name: install uploaded rpms
  command: rpm -ivh /tmp/*.rpm
```

I want to do it using yum module, but don't know, how to tell it to install all rpms in a directory (not to specify name of each file).

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Search for "loops in Ansible".

Answer (score 8):

I think the best solution for this is as follows:

```
 - name: Find all rpm files in /tmp folder
   find:
     paths: "/tmp"
     patterns: "*.rpm"
   register: rpm_files
 
 - name: Setting rpm_list
   set_fact:
    rpm_list: "{{ rpm_files.files | map(attribute='path') | list}}"

 - name: installing the rpm files
   yum:
     name: "{{rpm_list}}"
     state: present
```

Looping through the files might cause Yum Lock issues. So this is better and efficient as we don't have to loop through all the files, instead we are passing a list of file paths to the yum module.

Comment: Thanks for this, been pulling my hair on this.

Comment: What does "{{ rpm_files.files | map(attribute='path') | list}}" do exactly?

Comment: @Jontia reads the `register` variable `rpm_files`, gets the .files property from that object, pipes that value to a map function that extracts the .path property from each rpm "files" object (returned from the ansible `find` module), and concatenates each item into a list. it's a jinja template that sets the value of `rpm_list`

Answer (score 6):

Can you try this(I didn't test it):

```
- name: Finding RPM files
  find:
    paths: "/tmp"
    patterns: "*.rpm"
  register: rpm_result

- name: Install RPM
  yum:
    name: "{{ item.path }}"
    state: present
  with_items: "{{ rpm_result.files }}"
```

Comment: The solution doesn't work the same way as yum *.rpm since it install the files in the order of rpm_result.files and could fail on dependencies

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
- name: Installed the rpm files
  shell: yum localinstall *.rpm -y
  args:
    chdir: /tmp/rpm_dir
```

ignore the warning.

Comment: could add a `warn: false` for the warning

Answer (score 0):

As https://stackoverflow.com/a/45708676/11887927 commented and I tested. In most cases, it succeeded but adding `retries` to the task will help ensure the dependencies problems since we're using `find` module and it returns the results **one by one**. Here is the example of the revised:

```
- name: Finding RPM files
  find:
    paths: "/tmp"
    patterns: "*.rpm"
  register: rpm_result

- name: Install RPM
  yum:
    name: "{{ item.path }}"
    state: present
  with_items: "{{ rpm_result.files }}"
  retries: 5
  register: result
  until: result.rc == 0
```

The issue happened when there are 6 RPMs.

References:

1. https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#retrying-a-task-until-a-condition-is-met
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/44135131/11887927