# PostgreSQL Port not ready for an ansible task

Tags: postgresql, ansible

I'm almost finished with the setup for an PostgreSQL HA Ansible role between the master and slave node, but it keeps failing with one command:

```
- name: Create base backup
  command: pg_basebackup -X stream -D {{ postgres_home }} -h {{ master_ip }} -U {{ replica_user }}
  become: yes
  become_user: postgres
```

Error output of Ansible:

```
"stderr": "pg_basebackup: could not connect to server: could not connect to server: Connection refused\n\tIs the server running on host \"10.44.164.159\" and accepting\n\tTCP/IP connections on port 5432?",
    "stderr_lines": [
        "pg_basebackup: could not connect to server: could not connect to server: Connection refused",
        "\tIs the server running on host \"10.44.164.159\" and accepting",
        "\tTCP/IP connections on port 5432?"
```

But when I run this command after failing the playbook it runs without any erros and it succeeds.

Why does it works without Ansible and not within a role and playbook?

Thank you!

Comment: are you sure the port 5432 is ready on the target IP when the task is launched, did you wait the port to be ready with the module `wait_for`?

Comment: Yes, I have changed the position of starting the PostgreSQL Service and now with some time between it it works. Thank you

Comment: ok great so, can I submit an answer so you can set the question as answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to add a task before this task to wait the postgresql server to be ready.

You can do this way

```
- name: hold until Postgresql is up and running
  wait_for:
    host "{{ master_ip }}"
    port: 5432
```

You can also look at the complete documentation [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/wait_for_module.html)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the port was abailable but connection wasn't established, so it fails. Instead of waiting for the port, I run the query and retry if it fails ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55190070/710162)):

```
- name: Create base backup
  command: pg_basebackup -X stream -D {{ postgres_home }} -h {{ master_ip }} -U {{ replica_user }}
  become: yes
  become_user: postgres
  retries: 5
  delay: 5
  register: result
  until: result is not failed
```