# get ansible to wait for ssh connection

Tags: ansible

How do you get ansible to wait or retry ssh connections? I have an ansible tsk that runs `govc` to upload a vm into vcenter but right after that I ssh into the machine to run commands like this:

```
  hosts: vcenter
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: Download GOVC
      get_url:
        url: https://github.com/vmware/govmomi/releases/download/v0.20.0/govc_linux_amd64.gz
        dest: /home/gkeadmin/govc_linux_amd64.gz
```

but doing it right after I get this: `fatal: [139.178.66.91]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: connect to host 1.2.3.4 port 22: Operation timed out", "unreachable": true}`

I rerun it again with the `--retry` command and then it continues. Seems like it just needs sometime before I can connect via ssh...how do I wait for an ssh connection to get established in ansible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to retry Ansible task that may fail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44134642/how-to-retry-ansible-task-that-may-fail)

Answer (score 0):

ansible supports retries. May this can help you.

```
---
- name: test
  retries: 2
  hosts: <hosts_name>
  tasks:
    - name: task
      <module_name>:
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add a section on the top of your playbook to wait for it, for example

```
---
- name: wait for ssh
  tasks:
  - wait_for:
      port: 22
      host: '{{ inventory_hostname }}'
    delegate_to: localhost
- name: my playbook
  hosts: vcenter
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
   - name: Download GOVC
  [ ... etc ... ]
```

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/wait_for_module.html#examples